# libc-start.c: No such file or directory after core dump

Tags: c++, debugging, input, file-io, gdb

So I have been working on a text-game in C++. It is a text-based building game. I have been able to solve every issue, and it is working fine until I got to this part. Currently I am working on loading and saving games to the storage device, but the program outputs "Segmentation fault (Core Dump)" at this part of the code:

```
int loadGame(std::string path){
    std::ifstream exists(path.c_str());

    if(exists){
        std::cout << "  File found, press any key to load . . . ";
        getch();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "  Error: file not found, press any key to continue . . ." << std::endl;
        getch();
        return 1;
    }
```

In case you're wondering, I am on linux, and have made my own "getch" function with:

```
int getch(void){
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr);

    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO);

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr);

    ch = getchar();

    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr);

    return ch;
}
```

Currently I call the loadGame function with an:

```
if(loadGame(readInputFile()) == 0)
```

`readInputFile()` is a function that does a simple std::cin and returns it. I could go on and on with all the code...

However right after the "File found..." the program crashes with that error... The weirdest thing? getch() has worked for me the whole time, and when I put it before the std::cout "File found", and getch worked. I debugged this in Code Blocks (my IDE), and got the following information:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In ?? () ()
287 libc-start.c: No such file or directory.
#2  0x00007ffff7216ec5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4019d0, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe428, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe418) at libc-start.c:287
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Something is smashing your stack. Try stepping through the code and see where that happens.

Comment: It happens right after the "File found"...

Comment: No matter what I put after that piece of code, the program crashes

Comment: If it crashes when you return from `loadGame`, that could mean that somewhere you are overflowing a stack-allocated buffer. You need to step through the code and see where that happen. Or even easier, run `valgrind` and have it tell you where your overflow is.